# Unable to validate host certificates, can't build Minecraft Forge 44.1.0

Tags: gradle, minecraft-forge

I wanted to configure Intellij to make Minecraft forge mod, but I get this error

```
Build file 'F:\OneDrive\Desktop\Apps\Forge\forge-1.19.3-44.1.0\build.gradle' line: 4

An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle', version: '5.1.+']
> Failed to apply plugin 'net.minecraftforge.gradle'.
   > Failed to validate certificate for host 'https://maven.minecraftforge.net/'. To disable this check, re-run with '-Dnet.minecraftforge.gradle.check.certs=false'.
```

Cannot resolve symbol 'Date'

Comment: Are you on a network that breaks the security of all of your connections?

Comment: Is the `Cannot resolve symbol 'Date'` part of the exception? If so, ensure you have an SDK configured: File, Project Structure, Project, SDK. It should be Java 17+ for Forge 44.1.